# How to set backup-count via code on Hazelcast?

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-aggregate

Is there any way to set backup-count dynamically on Hazelcast via java?
Reading the [official documentation](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html-single/#creating-sync-backups), I could only find the configuration option backup-count but no reference on how to set it via java.

Thank You Very Much,
Geraldo Netto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always set Hazelcast config parameters using XML, YAML, or Java. The configuration looks the same. In the case of the backup-count, you can set it in Java using the following code:

```
config.getMapConfig("my-map").setBackupCount(2);
```

Comment: Thank You Very Very Much for your prompt answer @rafał-leszko!
If you allow me to ask, do you know how Hazelcast behaves with nodes that are not covered by the backup-count?

e.g.: imagine a situation where my cluster has 2 nodes and backup-count = 1, then, I add another node. So, the cluster has 3 nodes but a backup-count = 1, what happens with this third node that is not covered by backup-count?

Thank You so much once again :)

Comment: backup-count just means on how many other nodes you store the partition backup. So, if the third member joins, the partitions will be redistributed and each of the members stores some partitions and some backups of some other partitions. With backup-count=1, you're guaranteed that if 1 member crashes you don't loose the data.